# Http statuscode with GWT Requestfactory

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

if I use the GWT Requestfactory, what is the recommended way to send a "404 not found" or "401 unauthorized" to the client?

Greetings Andreas

Answer (score 6):

RequestFactory is an *RPC* kind of protocol, not a *REST* one. So, first, you won't send a "404 not found": that would mean your client app doesn't even know how to communicate with the server.

As for the "401 unauthorized", well, *it depends*.

- if you want to protect the access to the `RequestFactoryServlet` as a whole, then use a servlet filter on the server-side to send the response, and use a custom `RequestTransport` (easiest is to simply extend `DefaultRequestTransport`) on the client side to *catch* the response and act accordingly.
- if you want to protect only a few methods, or allow access to some methods only to specific users (e.g. only administrators are allowed to call method `deleteThisThing`), then you have several choices, but in all cases you don't want to ever call these methods from the client app if the user is not authorized (e.g. don't display a *delete this thing* button if the user is not an administrator):

  - do it in the method itself, throwing an exception (you can use `RequestFactoryServlet.getThreadLocalRequest().getUserPrincipal()` to get the current user)
  - use a `ServiceLayerDecorator` where you override the `invoke` method to do the check (possibly based on some annotation on the method itself) and call `report()` in case the user is not authorized

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I only want to protect a few methods, so I am doing it in the method itself. Am I right that I can't throw subtypes of exception with requestfactory? I want to throw a 404 when the client makes a request to edit an object that has already been deleted (client data may not always be 100% up to date). If the method needs authorization and the client is not logged in, I wanne throw an 401.

Comment: @ Thomas, I want to "protect only a few methods, or allow access to some methods only to specific users", Is it possible to do it in servelt filter ?

Comment: This is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525787/gwt-servlet-filter-how-to-identify-special-service-request